# How to know if a string contains more numeric pattern than alphabetic pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I want to know if my string contains more numbers or more alphabets.

I have tried using regex in python and putting a condition in between.

```
search_3 = '(\d) > (\D)'
words["aplha_or_numeric_mark"] = words["Words"].str.findall(search_3)
print(words)
```

The actual result is just an empty list on each row

**Expected results** :

123ABCD should output 1 since alphabets > numbers.

1234ABC should output 0 since alphabets < numbers.

Comment: You may want to read more about regular expressions, because they don't do what you think they do. From Wikipedia: "A regular expression is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern. Usually this pattern is used by string searching algorithms for "find" or "find and replace" operations on strings".

Comment: Okay. then how else can this problem be approached ?

Comment: To do what you need, you can simply scan through the string, and count letters and numbers separately, then decide what to return.

Comment: What if alphabets = numbers?

Comment: Thank you. this condition is a good point and I can include it in the solutions provided here.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
string = "ABCD12345"

num_count = 0
word_count = 0
for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        word_count += 1
    elif i.isdigit():
        num_count += 1
if word_count > num_count:
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do using `zip` on a generator:

```
def is_alpha_more(s):
    total_alphas, total_nums = zip(*((x.isalpha(), x.isdigit()) for x in s))
    return 1 if sum(total_alphas) >= sum(total_nums) else 0
```

**Sample run**:

```
>>> s = '12,"BCD'
>>> is_alpha_more(s)
1
>>> s = '1234A,":B'
>>> is_alpha_more(s)
0
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a better option.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input. will try with "Zip" too.

Comment: @tiredcoder, please accept one of the answers by pressing a tick on left of the answer you find helpful.

Comment: Yes. Done that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `re.findall` to find the count of both and get the results?

```
import re

s = '123ABCD'

numAlphabets = len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s))
numDigits = len(re.findall('\d', s))

if numAlphabets > numDigits:
 print('More alphabets then digits')
elif numDigits > numAlphabets:
 print('More digits then alphabets')
else:
 print('Same numbers for both')
```

For this case it prints,

```
More alphabets then digits
```

Also, if all you want to return 1 if more alphabets and 0 if less alphabets then digits, you can use this function,

```
import re

def has_more_alphabets(s):
 if len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s)) > len(re.findall('\d', s)):
  return 1
 else:
  return 0


print(has_more_alphabets('123ABCD'))
print(has_more_alphabets('123@@334ABCD'))
print(has_more_alphabets('123###ad553353455ABCD'))
print(has_more_alphabets('123BCD'))
```

Prints following,

```
1
0
0
0
```

Comment: Glad to help dear :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish what you ask. Regular expressions are meant for "search" or "search and replace" in strings. You need to count. One example would be something like:

```
def test_string(text):
    count_letters = 0
    count_digits = 0
    for character in text:
        if character.isalpha():
           count_letters += 1
        elif character.isdigit():
           count_digits += 1
    if count_letters > count_digits:
       return 1
    return 0
```

You still haven't defined what should happen if the two numbers are equal, but that should be easy case to add.